# Unable to unhide pivot items after setting visible = false once - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to show / hide pivot items based on a drop down selection.

If you see the code below, cell S3 is a drop down with options - All, Jan, Feb.. Dec. When I change the drop down, I want to show only the pivot items of the selected month.

What is happening here is, once I set an item visibility to false, I am not able to make it visible again. So, the for each loop below simply ignores those items that have been hidden earlier

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pt As PivotTable, counter
Dim pi As PivotItem, msg, mname

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Address = "$S$3" Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set pt = Sheet3.PivotTables(1)

    mname = Sheet2.Range("S3").Value
    pt.RefreshTable

    For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("Values").PivotItems
        If InStr(pi, mname) > 0 Or mname = "All" Then
            pi.Visible = True
        Else
            pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[Screenshot of my Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NepO4.png)

Comment: just a question, why not use a Slicer ? it will do exactly this, without VBA, and it even looks nice

Comment: I am trying to filter the values on x-axis. Slicer does not give me that option.

Comment: at which worksheet module do you have this code ? `Sheet3` ? `Sheet2` ? another sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code as commnets):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pf As PivotField

Dim msg As String, mname As String
'Dim counter ' <-- not used in this piece of code

If Target.Address = "$S$3" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' set the PivotTable object
    Set pt = Sheet3.PivotTables(1)

    mname = Target.Value ' <-- you can use the Target object
    pt.RefreshTable

    ' set the PivotField object
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Values")
    pf.ClearAllFilters ' clear all previous filters from "Values"

    ' if value is "All", show all items, (no need to run the loop)
    If mname <> "All" Then
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            If Not pi.Name Like "*" & mname & "*" Then ' only if the value is not like the month >> hide the PivotItem
                pi.Visible = False
            End If
        Next pi
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I am getting Application error on the step -     pf.ClearAllFilters '

Comment: @Archana at which line are you getting this error ?

Comment: pf.ClearAllFilters